# Не работает проверка checkbox на js

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Не работает простейшая проверка чекбокса. `alert` всегда выводит No. Не могу понять, в чём проблема

```js
let check = document.getElementById('valueName');

if (check.checked) {
  alert('Yes');
} else {
  alert('No')
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="valueName">
<label for="valueName">Чекбокс</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас происходит единственная проверка в момент инициализации скрипта. В это время чекбокс неактивен, поэтому выводится `No`. Чтобы проверять изменение состояния чекбокса необходимо добавить слушатель для такого события:

```js
let check = document.getElementById('valueName');

check.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (check.checked) {
    alert('Yes');
  } else {
    alert('No')
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="valueName">
<label for="valueName">Чекбокс</label>
```